# After updates my system won't boot into LXDE, X is running but screen stays black

Tags: xorg, display-manager

The task bar tries to load, flashing white a few times but then stops and screen stays black, and mouse cursor is available.

Here are my updates:

```
Commit Log for Sat Oct 17 10:46:41 2015
Removed the following packages:
cantarell-fonts
lib64gtop2.0_7
lib64pango1.0_0-modules

Upgraded the following packages:
at-spi2-core (2.12.0-1pclos2014) to 2.18.1-1pclos2015
curl (7.43.0-1pclos2015) to 7.45.0-1pclos2015
dbus (1.8.10-1pclos2014) to 1.8.20-1pclos2015
dbus-x11 (1.8.10-1pclos2014) to 1.8.20-1pclos2015
dhcp-client (4.3.2-1pclos2015) to 4.3.3-1pclos2015
dhcp-common (4.3.2-1pclos2015) to 4.3.3-1pclos2015
ffmpeg (2.7.2-1pclos2015) to 2.8-1pclos2015
gcr (3.10.1-1pclos2014) to 3.18.0-1pclos2015
gdk-pixbuf2.0 (2.31.2-1pclos2015) to 2.32.1-1pclos2015
gettext (0.19.4-1pclos2015) to 0.19.6-1pclos2015
gettext-base (0.19.4-1pclos2015) to 0.19.6-1pclos2015
gvfs (1.24.1-1pclos2015) to 1.26.0-1pclos2015
java-1.8.0-sun (1.8.0.51-1pclos2015) to 1.8.0.60-1pclos2015
java-1.8.0-sun-alsa (1.8.0.51-1pclos2015) to 1.8.0.60-1pclos2015
java-1.8.0-sun-devel (1.8.0.51-1pclos2015) to 1.8.0.60-1pclos2015
java-1.8.0-sun-fonts (1.8.0.51-1pclos2015) to 1.8.0.60-1pclos2015
java-1.8.0-sun-jdbc (1.8.0.51-1pclos2015) to 1.8.0.60-1pclos2015
java-1.8.0-sun-plugin (1.8.0.51-1pclos2015) to 1.8.0.60-1pclos2015
lib64atspi0 (2.12.0-1pclos2014) to 2.18.1-1pclos2015
lib64avcodec56 (2.7.2-1pclos2015) to 2.8-1pclos2015
lib64avfilter5 (2.7.2-1pclos2015) to 2.8-1pclos2015
lib64avformat56 (2.7.2-1pclos2015) to 2.8-1pclos2015
lib64avutil54 (2.7.2-1pclos2015) to 2.8-1pclos2015
lib64blkid1 (2.22.2-4pclos2015) to 2.27-3pclos2015
lib64curl4 (7.43.0-1pclos2015) to 7.45.0-1pclos2015
lib64dbus-1_3 (1.8.10-1pclos2014) to 1.8.20-1pclos2015
lib64drm2 (2.4.62-1pclos2015) to 2.4.65-2pclos2015
lib64gcr3_1 (3.10.1-1pclos2014) to 3.18.0-1pclos2015
lib64gdk_pixbuf2.0_0 (2.31.2-1pclos2015) to 2.32.1-1pclos2015
lib64gettextmisc (0.19.4-1pclos2015) to 0.19.6-1pclos2015
lib64gksu2.0_0 (2.0.12-3pclos2013) to 2.0.12-5pclos2015
lib64glib2.0_0 (2.44.1-1pclos2015) to 2.46.1-1pclos2015
lib64gvfs0 (1.24.1-1pclos2015) to 1.26.0-1pclos2015
lib64intl8 (0.19.4-1pclos2015) to 0.19.6-1pclos2015
lib64ldap2.4_2 (2.4.23-2pclos2014) to 2.4.23-3pclos2015
lib64lm_sensors4 (3.3.5-2pclos2014) to 3.4.0-1pclos2015
lib64mount1 (2.22.2-4pclos2015) to 2.27-3pclos2015
lib64mtp9 (1.1.8-1pclos2014) to 1.1.9-2pclos2015
lib64pango1.0_0 (1.36.8-1pclos2015) to 1.38.1-1pclos2015
lib64postproc53 (2.7.2-1pclos2015) to 2.8-1pclos2015
lib64pulseaudio0 (6.0-1pclos2015) to 7.0-1pclos2015
lib64pulseglib20 (6.0-1pclos2015) to 7.0-1pclos2015
lib64swresample1 (2.7.2-1pclos2015) to 2.8-1pclos2015
lib64swscaler3 (2.7.2-1pclos2015) to 2.8-1pclos2015
lib64uuid1 (2.22.2-4pclos2015) to 2.27-3pclos2015
libgtop2 (2.28.5-1pclos2014) to 2.32.0-3pclos2015
libmtp-utils (1.1.8-1pclos2014) to 1.1.9-2pclos2015
llvm (3.6.2-1pclos2015) to 3.7.0-1pclos2015
lm_sensors (3.3.5-2pclos2014) to 3.4.0-1pclos2015
mesa (10.6.3-2pclos2015) to 11.0.3-1pclos2015
openldap (2.4.23-2pclos2014) to 2.4.23-3pclos2015
openssh (6.6p1-1pclos2014) to 7.1p1-3pclos2015
openssh-askpass-gnome (6.6p1-1pclos2014) to 7.1p1-3pclos2015
openssh-clients (6.6p1-1pclos2014) to 7.1p1-3pclos2015
openssh-server (6.6p1-1pclos2014) to 7.1p1-3pclos2015
pango (1.36.8-1pclos2015) to 1.38.1-1pclos2015
pulseaudio (6.0-1pclos2015) to 7.0-1pclos2015
pulseaudio-esound-compat (6.0-1pclos2015) to 7.0-1pclos2015
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth (6.0-1pclos2015) to 7.0-1pclos2015
pulseaudio-module-equalizer (6.0-1pclos2015) to 7.0-1pclos2015
pulseaudio-module-gconf (6.0-1pclos2015) to 7.0-1pclos2015
pulseaudio-module-jack (6.0-1pclos2015) to 7.0-1pclos2015
pulseaudio-module-lirc (6.0-1pclos2015) to 7.0-1pclos2015
pulseaudio-module-x11 (6.0-1pclos2015) to 7.0-1pclos2015
pulseaudio-module-zeroconf (6.0-1pclos2015) to 7.0-1pclos2015
pulseaudio-utils (6.0-1pclos2015) to 7.0-1pclos2015
sysvinit (2.88-3pclos2013) to 2.88-4pclos2015
sysvinit-tools (2.88-3pclos2013) to 2.88-4pclos2015
util-linux-ng (2.22.2-4pclos2015) to 2.27-3pclos2015

Installed the following packages:
abattis-cantarell-fonts (0.0.17.2-1pclos2015)
fontpackages-filesystem (1.44-1pclos2014)
lib64datrie1 (0.2.4-1pclos2011)
lib64dconf1 (0.24.0-2pclos2015)
lib64fdisk1 (2.27-3pclos2015)
lib64gio2.0_0 (2.46.1-1pclos2015)
lib64gtop2.0_10 (2.32.0-3pclos2015)
lib64poppler54 (0.35.0-1pclos2015)
lib64smartcols1 (2.27-3pclos2015)
lib64thai0 (0.1.19-1pclos2013)
lib64wxgtku3.0_0 (3.0.2-5pclos2015)
thai-data (0.1.19-1pclos2013)
wxgtk (3.0.2-5pclos2015)
```

No errors showing in my Xorg.0.log
This is my .xsession-errors: 
localhost being added to access control list
/etc/X11/Xsession: line 137: type: -v: invalid option
type: usage: type [-afptP] name [name ...]
xterm: fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) or KillClient on X server ":0"

When I launched openbox I got:

> "failed to open the display from the DISPLay environmental 
>   variable"

I installed icewm-light but when I tried it I got:

> "X must be running and $DISPLAY set"

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked in the log files (under `/var/log/`) to see what error messages are being produced? It would be worth looking in particular at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` or the equivalent on your system. (Please remember to [edit] your question to include any additional information. Don't leave it to get lost in the comments.)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED - simply ran apt-get upgrade.
 As noted above it seemed to be a problem loading lxde resulting from package updates. 
I still don't know which packages were involved in the problem or solution.